# Android - Buttons not working when i call Activity for the second time

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an App that has 2 activities, the main activity (HomeActivity) has a List with the information of different objects, i can click on this objects and an alert dialog will appear that can launch my second activity (ServerConfig) that will display the information of the selected object along with some other functionality, now here is the problem, when i just compile the project and call this activity for the first it works like a charm, but if I go back and then select the same or an other object on the list and call this Activity ServerConfig, it will load and display the new information but the buttons that i put on the bottom don't work anymore, they just do nothing, this buttons are on a separate  , but the button that is on the other LinearLayout works just fine. The sevice of this applications is telling me that the job was send when i clicked the button but nothing changes on the activity.

here are the files:

XML for the ServerConfig Activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/serConfig_Title"
                style="@style/textHeading"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/serConfig_title" />

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/serConfig_serDetailsTable"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/serConfig_Title"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:padding="10dp" >

                <TableRow>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/serConfig_server_name" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/serConfig_serverName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/server_name_dummy" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/serConfig_server_address" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/serConfig_serverAddress"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/server_address_dummy" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/port_title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/serConfig_port"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/port_dummy" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/protocol_title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/serConfig_protocol"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/port_dummy" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/notification_title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/serNotif_email"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/port_dummy" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/serNotif_sms"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/port_dummy" />
                </TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/serConfig_historyButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/serConfig_hist_Butt" />
            </TableLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/serConfig_welcomeLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/serConfig_serDetailsTable"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/serConfig_welcomeMsgOld"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/serConfig_welcomeMsgOld"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textIsSelectable="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/serConfig_welcomeMsg"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/serConfig_welcomeMsg"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textIsSelectable="true" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/serConfig_progBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/serConfig_welcomeLayout"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/serConfig_connButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/serConfig_conn_Butt" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/serConfig_accpLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/serConfig_accpButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/serConfig_accept_Butt" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/serConfig_rejButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/serConfig_reject_Butt" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Part ServerConfig Activity

```
public class ServerConfigActivityP extends Activity {

    /**
     * View/Helper for this Activity.
     */
    private ServerConfigView m_ServerView;
    /**
     * Selected Server that will be display in this Activity.
     */
    private ServerDetails m_SelectedServer;
    /**
     * Selected servers position in the DatabaseManager.
     */
    private int m_ServerPosition;

    private boolean m_serviceIsBound = false;
    private ServerService m_service = null;

    private static final String TAG_DEBUG ="SERVER_CONFIG_ACTIVITY";

    private Button AcceptButton,RejectButton,ConnectButton,HistoryButton;
    /**
     * Activity life cycle onCreate.
     * 
     *  Gets the ServerDetails that we are going to use for this Activity.
     *  Display the information of the selected ServerDetails.
     * 
     * @see Activity
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_server_config_activity_p);


        this.AcceptButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.serConfig_accpButton);
        this.RejectButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.serConfig_rejButton);
        this.ConnectButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.serConfig_connButton);
        this.HistoryButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.serConfig_historyButton);

        AcceptButton.setOnClickListener(myListener);
        RejectButton.setOnClickListener(myListener);
        ConnectButton.setOnClickListener(myListener);
        HistoryButton.setOnClickListener(myListener);



        // Create the ServerConfigView for this Activity
        m_ServerView = new ServerConfigView(this);

        // Get the selected ServerDetails from the Intent.
        Bundle recBundle = new Bundle();
        recBundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra(ServerDetails.TAG_SELECTED_SERVER);

        // Get the position in the List of the ServerDetaisl that we are going to use for this activity.
        m_ServerPosition = recBundle.getInt(ServerDBM.TAG_SERVER_POSITION);

        // Get the ServerDetails Object that we are going to use for this activity We Make a deep Copy.
        m_SelectedServer = new ServerDetails(ServerDBM.getServerAtPosition(m_ServerPosition));

        // Show the information of the Selected ServerDetails on this Activity.
        m_ServerView.ShowOnScreen(m_SelectedServer);

        m_SelectedServer.setSerName("JobConfigActivity");
        //Bind This Activity with the Service
        doBindService();

    }

    private OnClickListener myListener = new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.serConfig_connButton:
                executeJobOnService();
                m_ServerView.WaitForResponce();
                Log.i(TAG_DEBUG,"Connect Button Pressed");
                break;
            // Show History Button: Displays the History of the selected ServerDetails Initialize a new Activity.
            case R.id.serConfig_historyButton:
                m_ServerView.showHistory(m_SelectedServer.getIpAdd());
                break;

            case R.id.serConfig_accpButton:
                storeNewMessage();
                storeMonResult();
                HomeView.refreshListView();
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.serConfig_rejButton:
                storeMonResult();
                m_ServerView.ShowAcceptAndRejetButtons(false);
                m_ServerView.ShowConnectButton(true);
                m_ServerView.resetEverything();
                break;

            }

        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        doUnbindService();
        HomeView.refreshListView();
        Log.d(TAG_DEBUG, "Server Config Activity Destroyed");

    }
//More Code !!
}
```

Calling the ServerConfig Activity from the HomeActivity

```
final Intent configIntent = new         
Intent(m_presenter,ServerConfigActivityP.class);
Bundle selServer = new Bundle();
selServer.putInt(ServerDBM.TAG_SERVER_POSITION,position);
configIntent.putExtra(ServerDetails.TAG_SELECTED_SERVER,selServer);
// Start the Server ConfigActivity
m_presenter.startActivity(configIntent);
```

Comment: Nobody is going to read such a fat question. If he read also he ll get confused. It is better to provide a Short, Working and Compact question with a compact code or a part of it

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have shown I can't see where you connect `myListener` defined with your buttons.

To operate correctly you should define OnClick-listenters for buttons (connect them) in `OnCreate()` or in `OnResume()` methods.